# Dependencies not installing from lib directory in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, web-deployment

As far as I can tell, I have set up my flask app right. lib, containing all dependencies is at my root, and contains what Requirements.txt has in it. my `appengine_config.py` contains the below

```
print 'running app  config yaya!'

from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os
import sys


print os.path
print os.path.realpath
print os.path.realpath(__file__)

print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib')

sys.path.insert(0,'./lib')
vendor.add('lib')
print 'I am the line after adding lib, it should have worked'
```

per all those print statements, nothing is erroring, but I am getting

`No module named flask_sqlalchemy`

after deploying and seeing a 500. What am I missing to  get these suckers installed?

EDIT---------------
thanks and here --

```
running app  config yaya!
18:36:29.499
['./lib', '/base/data/home/apps/s~nimble-poet-150223/20161221t183424.397920801519685819', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/markupsafe-0.15', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1', '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']
18:36:29.499
```

### at print dir(vendor)

```
['PYTHON_VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'add', 'os', 'site', 'sys']
18:36:29.503
```

### at final print statement

```
I am the line after adding lib, it should have worked
18:36:29.948
```

### the error

```
(/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
        handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
        handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
        obj = __import__(path[0])
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~nimble-poet-150223/20161221t183424.397920801519685819/main.py", line 6, in <module>
        from nimble import *
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~nimble-poet-150223/20161221t183424.397920801519685819/nimble/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, SignallingSession
    ImportError: No module named flask_sqlalchemy
    18:36:30.191
    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Not sure if it is related, but I am also getting https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=729
but that fix doesnt help

---more edits

I moved everything from /site_pakcages up a dir to /lib and I am alot closer, some of my pages are even working! but now I get

`ImportError: No module named _sqlite3`

but the code reads

```
except ImportError as e:
try:
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
except ImportError as ee:
raise ee
return sqlite
```

why would there be an underscore in the import attempt here? help?

Comment: Why are you manually fiddling with `sys.path`? `vendor.add('lib')` should take care of it, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library

Comment: What does the app log view shows for that 500? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer Maybe show the entire stack trace?

Comment: was just doing sys directly since vendor is yet to do the trick ill try again

Comment: Make sure your `lib` directory has an `__init__.py`

Comment: thanks, trying that now. why would that make a difference though? is that documented?

Comment: I did that, the error is now 
`python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @GAEfan: I don't think an `__init__.py` is needed in the `lib` dir - it's not a package itself, it's just a dir where one or more packages exist. I don't have one, for example :)

Comment: its the only thing that got me closer... now I am getting

`  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~nimble-poet-150223/20161222t115429.397937562988965799/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~nimble-poet-150223/20161222t115429.397937562988965799/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 339, in dbapi
    raise ee
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3`

but can't figure out how to rebuild the core py installation and get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr: use appengine_config.py and copy your virtualenv to a folder called lib, then make SURE you are running the app via dev_appserver.py

(the below is via bash in ubuntu) SO after a long battle, I find that virtual env and gcloud dont play nice -

I copied everything from my virtual env dir

.../.virtualenvs/nimble/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

into

[projectdir]/lib

and my appengine_config.py finally worked locally like it does in the cloud, but I absolutely HAVE to run

```
dev_appserver.py [my proj dir here]
```

or the google.appengine module wont load. did not know I should be using dev server. I feel very dumb.

for reference, heres the appengine_config.py

```
"""`appengine_config` gets loaded when starting a new application instance."""

print 'running app  config yaya!'

from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
print 'I am the line after adding lib, it should have worked'
import os
print os.getcwd()
```